# React Router 6 navigate to new tab with state

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How to add target='_blank' in navigate?

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const navigate = useNavigate();

navigate(`/record`, {
      state: {
        eventId: event.id,
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `navigate` function isn't capable of doing this, it can only navigate within the app in the same window/tab.

You can use the following:

- `Link` passing a `target="_blank"` prop.

  ```
  <Link to="/record" target="_blank">
    /record
  </Link>
  ```
- Anchor tag using a `target="_blank"` attribute.

  ```
  <a href="/record" target="_blank">
    /record
  </a>
  ```
- `window.open` in a callback.

  ```
  const navigateOutApp = () => window.open("/record", "_blank", "noreferrer");

  ...

  <button type="button" onClick={navigateOutApp}>
    /record
  </button>
  ```
- If you need to also pass "state" then you will need to temporarily store it in localStorage and retrieve it when the app and target component mount.

  ```
  const navigateExternal = (target, options) => {
    if (options.state) {
      localStorage.setItem("state", JSON.stringify(options.state));
    }
    window.open(target, "_blank", "noreferrer");
  };
  ```

  ```
  const Bar = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("state")));

    const location = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => {
      localStorage.removeItem("state");
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (location.state) {
        setState(location.state);
      }
    }, [location]);

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("Passed state", { state });
    }, [state]);

    return (
      <>
        <h1>Bar</h1>
        <div>State: {JSON.stringify(state)}</div>
      </>
    );
  };
  ```

### Demo

[image: Edit react-router-6-navigate-to-new-tab-with-state]

Comment: then I can't pass state to a new tab?

Comment: @VinceFrost Ah, sorry, missed that bit. For that you'll need to store what you want to pass in "state" in localStorage to be retrieved in the new browser context. I've updated my sandbox with internal/external examples with passing state.

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can use a simple approach for this

```js
<Link to="/yourRoute" target="_blank">
    Take me to other page
</Link>
```

According to `react-router-dom` the `<a>` tag is replaced by `<Link>` tag so you can use all `<a>` tag attributes on `Link` tag.