# How can I open new page with route URL in React Router 6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am configure the react route like this right now:

```
import Home from "@/page/home/Home";
import PaySuccess from "@/page/pay/success/PaySuccess";
import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const routes = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />
    },
    {
        path: "/product/pay/success",

        element: <PaySuccess />
    },
]);

export default routes;
```

now I want to open a new page(open the page in new tab, not open a app new page) when access the url `/product/pay/success`, how to configure? the router version is `"react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",`. I am searching from internet and read the doc https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router, seems did not mention it. is it possible? This is the `index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store/store';
import { RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import routes from './redux/routes/routes';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RouterProvider router={routes} />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

I have tried like this:

```
{
    path: "/product/pay/success",
    target: '_blank',
    element: <PaySuccess />,
},
```

Comment: Are you just wanting to navigate to a new page in the app or are you trying to open a new browsing context, e.g. a new browser window or tab? If the former then use the `Link`, `NavLink`, or `Navigate` components, or `navigate` function, to navigate to the page. If the latter then I think you may need a raw anchor (*`<a>`*) tag with the appropriate link attributes or use `window.open`.

Comment: I want to open a new browser window/tab.

Comment: I could not use window open because this is a callback url, the third party website will callback the url, I could not control. could you explain for mire details.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. You can't specify this in the route configuration, but you can with the links. Where are you attempting to navigate to `"/product/pay/success"`? Can you [edit] the post to share a [mcve] where you are effecting the navigation action?

Comment: the url `/product/pay/success` will be called when the pay success, the pay provider service will callback this url. I just define the url and component, but I still want to open the component in new browser tab page.

Comment: The pay provider, the one linking to the URL, i.e. your app, should be the one to open the URL in a new browsing context then.

Answer (score 1):

## Redirecting a User in React

### Introduction

In this document, we'll go over how to redirect a user in a React application.

### Scenario

You want to redirect the user to a certain URL when something happens in your React app. The question is, what is that "something"?

#### If it is a click on a Link component:

```js
<Link to="/product/pay/success" params={myParams} target="_blank" />
```

#### If it is on component mount:

1. Determine what should be happening on the 1st tab (that was opened before)
2. Create a brand new Route and use it for the callback URL, let's name it `/temp_success`

```js
{
  path: "/product/pay/success",
  element: <PaySuccess />
},
{
  path: "/temp_success",
  element: <OpenNewTabAndRedirectSuccess />
}
```

3. Write the code for this redirect functionality

```js
export const OpenNewTabAndRedirectSuccess = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.open("/product/pay/success", "_blank", "noreferrer");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      Content that will stay on the original page.
      Otherwise, use navigate function from link below
    </div>
  );
};
```

#### Further Resources

- [React Router's useNavigate Hook](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate)
- [React Router 6 navigate to new tab with state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73577234/react-router-6-navigate-to-new-tab-with-state)